# Puppeteer Scraping Tables without distinct classes

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Although not a beginner, I'm having difficulty **cleanly** scraping tables that don't have targetted classes/id's. Also, the data is in weird spots and sometimes does even exist.

This is my current project: http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/OverviewForComplaintServlet?complaintno=3732304

I need the following data:
[image]

and I need to output it in a array of key/value pairs.

Just using the browsers console:

```
let tables = document.querySelectorAll('table') // get all tables
tables.forEach(table => document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => console.log(tr.innerText)))
```

I get this ugly text which I have to parse through and there are so many variables to consider the file turning into a 500 line monster.

Any ideas for a better way to do this?

[image]

EDIT: Additional question
This is particular hard to parse. How do you get just the first number here? Splitting by `split('&bnsp;')` does not work too well.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably start by first trying to individually print each cell. That will give you a much better idea of the structure.

```js
let tableNum = 0;
let rowNum = 0;
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
tables.forEach(table => {
    console.log(`Table: ${tableNum++}`);
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    rows.forEach(row => {
        console.log(`Row: ${rowNum++}`);
        const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
        cells.forEach(cell => console.log(cell.innerText));
    });
    rowNum = 0;
});
```

Also, if `class` and `id` are not present on the tables, you can try to target any other attribute that might help you into targeting the elements more specifically.

Comment: I posted my working version. Not a fan of it though. Pointers?

Comment: If it's working as expected then you should accept it. There's actually no point in trying to optimize code to "look better" when it's working unless, it can be made to perform faster. Also, running fast is not a key requirement for all cases. One small change might be to cache `tr.innerText` in a variable before the if statements since you are calling `tr.innerText` but that's just nitpicking here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up creating, but I'm not a fan of the if statements. Anyone else got any better ideas?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

module.exports = async function crawler(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(url);

  let results = [];

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let results = [];
    Array(document.querySelectorAll("table")).map((tables) => {
      tables.forEach((table) => {
        table.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((tr) => {
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Overview")) {
            results.push({ status: tr.innerText.split("=")[1].trim() });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Category Code")) {
            results.push({
              "Category Code": tr.innerText
                .split("\t")[1]
                .split("")
                .splice(0, 2)
                .join(""),
            });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Assigned To:")) {
            results.push({ "Assigned To": tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim() });
            results.push({
              Priority: tr.innerText.split("\t")[2].split(":")[1].trim(),
            });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Received:")) {
            results.push({ Received: tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim() });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Owner:")) {
            results.push({ owner: tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim() });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Last Inspection:")) {
            results.push({
              "Last Inspection": tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim(),
            });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Disposition:")) {
            results.push({
              Disposition: tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim(),
            });
          }
          if (tr.innerText.includes("Comments:")) {
            results.push({
              comments: tr.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim(),
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
    return results;
  });

  data.forEach((item) => results.push(item));

  const inlineForm = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let results = [];
    Array(document.querySelectorAll(".inlineform")).map((tr) => {
      tr.forEach((r) => {
        results.push({ Number: r.innerText.split("\t")[0].trim() });
        results.push({ Date: r.innerText.split("\t")[1].trim() });
        results.push({ Code: r.innerText.split("\t")[2].trim() });
        results.push({ Disposition: r.innerText.split("\t")[3].trim() });
        results.push({ "Inspection By": r.innerText.split("\t")[4].trim() });
        results.push({ Date: r.innerText.split("\t")[5].trim() });
      });
    });
    return results;
  });

  inlineForm.forEach((item) => results.push(item));

  await browser.close();
  return results;
};
```